# Detecting number of checked checkboxes efficiently

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, checkbox

hiii,
I want to detect how many checkboxes are checked in given list checkboxes.
One method that I know is to check it by looping through the list and check one by one if it is checked

```
$('.chkBoxList').each(function() {
if($(this).is(':checked'))
{
     // do something
}
```

But I feel it is quite inefficient method. As if there are hundreds/thousands of checkboxes and only few of them are checked, it will still loop through all the checkboxes.

Is there any other way to improve it. I would be grateful if anyone can suggest an efficient alternative to it. Please guide me & suggest appropriate solution with pros & cons.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get all checked inputs (assuming there's no any radios) inside element with class `chkBoxList` and `length` property will be the count of them:

```
var cnt = $('.chkBoxList input:checked').length;
```

If your checkboxes have `chkBoxList` class use this:

```
var cnt = $('.chkBoxList:checked').length;
```

Comment: Hi @igor Dymov thanks for your reply.. Can I get the ids of the checked checkboxes?

Comment: i think if you want to get some another information you have to use `each`

Comment: `$(".chkBoxList:checked").each(function() { $("#someDiv").append($(this).attr("id"))});` << This will give you ids of checked checkboxes... :)

Comment: var ids = $(".chkBoxList:checked").map(function() { return parseInt(this.id, 10); });

That will give you an array of the id's of checked checkboxes (e.g: [1,4,54,33])

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.chkBoxList').filter(':checked').length
```